# Telerik kendo ui drawing exportPDF send to server

Tags: javascript, pdf, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I use this drawing feature from kendo ui ([here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/drawing))

and it works very well to export PDF for user

but i want to submit back the PDF to the server with AJAX.

why i want it?
i want to allow the customer to send an email with the PDF from my server

Answer (score 4):

here is the code to send request to server:

```
  kendo.drawing.drawDOM($("#statement-print-area"))
                  .then(function (group) {
                      // Render the result as a PDF file
                      return kendo.drawing.exportPDF(group, {
                          paperSize: "auto",
                          margin: { left: "1cm", top: "1cm", right: "1cm", bottom: "1cm" }
                      });
                  })
                  .done(function (data) {
                      $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          url: "/Customer/EmailStatement",
                          processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
                          contentType: false,  // tell jQuery not to set contentType
                          data: '{ "docData" : "' + data + '" ,"email": "' + vm.sendEmailTo + '"}',
                          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                          dataType: 'json',
                      }).done(handleResponseInfo).fail(ajaxError);
                  });
```

and here is the code on the server side (asp.net MVC)

```
            docData = docData.Replace("data:application/pdf;base64,", "");
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(docData);
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
new Attachment(stream, "Customer statement.pdf", "application/pdf")

                message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example:

```
<script>

    $(function () {
        $("#button0PDF").kendoButton();
        var button = $("#button0PDF").data("kendoButton");

        button.bind("click", function (e) {
            kendo.drawing.drawDOM("#divId", {
                forcePageBreak: ".page-break",
                //template: $("#page-template").html()

            })
            .then(function (group) {
                // Render the result as a PDF file
                return kendo.drawing.exportPDF(group, {
                    landscape: false
                });
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                // Save the PDF file
                kendo.saveAs({
                    dataURI: data,
                    fileName: "fileName.pdf",
                    proxyURL: "/API/Main/Post",
                });
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

And the server side part:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]FileData file)
        {
            var data = Convert.FromBase64String(file.Base64);

            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(data))
            };

            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(file.ContentType);

            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = file.FileName
            };

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is proxy Uri?.I am using spring mvc as backened.Can you tell the method for receiving the pdf data into spring mvc controller so that i can save it into database.When i receive in controller.java what will be the format of file?

Comment: U are taking something as [FromBody] inside server side method.Can you please tell what is this?

Comment: @SachinHR whats your controller? In my case is 'Main' and the method is 'Post' thats why proxyURL: "/API/Main/Post"